# How do wild muscovy ducklings get in and out of an elevated nest?

Tags: ducks

In the wild, muscovy ducks prefer to nest in tree cavities 10-65 feet above ground. From observing my domesticated muscovys, the mothers do not feed the ducklings, but take them out grazing. I would like to build them some elevated nest boxes that mimic their preferred nesting habitat as much as possible. How do the ducklings get in and out of an elevated nest in the wild?

Comment: they do not get in and out of the nest,only out,you can take a look here two min in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDJw43BJtCE

Comment: That's pretty incredible! Now it makes more sense why they have no fear of running straight off edges and over hills!